# One hot encoding a segmented image using pytorch

Tags: python, encoding, pytorch

I have a segmented image as a tensor of size `[1,1,256,256]`. The image is a binary segmented image. I want to one hot encode it to get an image of size `[1,2,256,256]`.
I tried `torch.nn.functional.one_hot(img, 2)`. But it gave me an image of size `[1,256,256,2]`. How do I get the desired tensor?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `transpose()`:

```py
img_one_hot = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(img, 2).transpose(1, 4).squeeze(-1)
```

`transpose(1, 4)` - swaps 1st and 4th dimension, returning the tensor of the shape of `[1, 2, 256, 256, 1]`, `squeeze(-1)` removes the last dim resulting in `[1 , 2, 256, 256]` shaped tensor.